# seeking a concise way to accumulate values

Tags: javascript

The following code produces the desired output but is there a more concise way to write it?  ie. one liner approaches

```js
const data = [
    { id: '385/72/21', month: 4 },
    { id: '385/72/21', month: 7 },
    { id: '385/72/21', month: 8 },
    { id: '385/72/21', month: 10 },
    { id: '461/80/07', month: 1 },
    { id: '461/80/07', month: 5 },
    { id: '461/80/07', month: 9 }
];

const accumulator = Object.assign({}, ...data.map(o => ({ [o.id]: [] })))
data.forEach(o => accumulator[o.id].push(o.month));
console.log(accumulator);
```

Comment: seems to be a nice use case for reducers

Comment: How much more "concise" are you looking for?

Comment: @ScottHunter One liner.

Comment: Why are you looping twice? `data.reduce((acc, o) => { acc[o.id] = acc[o.id] || [];  acc[o.id].push(o.month); return acc;}, {})` or `data.reduce((acc, o) => { acc[o.id] ??= [];  acc[o.id].push(o.month); return acc;}, {})`

Comment: @epascarello Thus the question of a more concise approach.

Comment: One line is not always better... unless you are playing code golf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer using the comma operator instead of spreading over and over again (depending on your dataset you may incur a [performance penalty](https://gist.github.com/customcommander/97eb4b3f1600773db59406d39f3f9cd7)):

```js
console.log(

  data.reduce((acc, {id, month}) =>
    (acc[id] ??= [], acc[id].push(month), acc), {})

);
```

```html
<script>
const data = [
    { id: '385/72/21', month: 4 },
    { id: '385/72/21', month: 7 },
    { id: '385/72/21', month: 8 },
    { id: '385/72/21', month: 10 },
    { id: '461/80/07', month: 1 },
    { id: '461/80/07', month: 5 },
    { id: '461/80/07', month: 9 }
];
</script>
```

Comment: This looks promising.  What is `??=`?

Comment: That looks good. nice

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: @knot22 means if not exist the push empty array. in this case.

Comment: I really want to use this solution and am trying to use it in a Vue 2.0 app and the console is showing `Support for the experimental syntax 'nullishCoalescingOperator' isn't currently enabled`.  I'm Googling for a solution to that.  If you happen to know how to fix that, I'd sure be interested.

Comment: Figured out a workaround for the unsupported `??` in Vue.  Replaced `acc[id] ??= [],` with `!acc[id] ? acc[id] = [] : null,` and it worked.  It's not as elegant as your solution but still an improvement over my original code.

Comment: Another workaround variation is replacing `acc[id] ??= []` with `acc[id] = acc[id] || []`.

Comment: That's a nice one! I should use comma operator more often too.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const data = [
    { id: '385/72/21', month: 4 },
    { id: '385/72/21', month: 7 },
    { id: '385/72/21', month: 8 },
    { id: '385/72/21', month: 10 },
    { id: '461/80/07', month: 1 },
    { id: '461/80/07', month: 5 },
    { id: '461/80/07', month: 9 }
];

const result = data.reduce((accu, curr) => {
    accu[curr.id] = Array.isArray(accu[curr.id]) ? [...accu[curr.id], curr.month] : [curr.month];
    return accu;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of using `Array.reduce()` to get the required output:

```js
const data = [ { id: '385/72/21', month: 4 }, { id: '385/72/21', month: 7 }, { id: '385/72/21', month: 8 }, { id: '385/72/21', month: 10 }, { id: '461/80/07', month: 1 }, { id: '461/80/07', month: 5 }, { id: '461/80/07', month: 9 } ];
const result = data.reduce((acc, { id, month}) => ({ ...acc, [id]: [ ...(acc[id] || []), month ]  }), {})

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
data.reduce((a, c) => (
    {...a, [c.id]: [...(a[c.id] || []), c.month]}
), {});
```